# Hartl tutorial Chapter 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am getting the follow error

> SyntaxError in StaticPagesController#home
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:14: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' ...link_to image_tag ("rails.png", alt: "Rails logo") , ... ^ /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:15: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end 'http://rubyonrails.org/' );@output_buffer.to_s ^

My rails.png is in the images file
my code is this i am getting the error in line 14 of home.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to image_tag ("rails.png", alt: "Rails logo") ,
      'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
```

Comment: I am not sure, but the main rule of ruby is: **do not put a space between function name and opening parenthesis**.

Comment: wow thanks ,that was it and i was looking it over and over ,i haven't noticed.Now i can't see the logo.Let's find out why .Thank you!

Comment: @clair13 restart your local server if your image isn't showing up.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i am getting the crashed image icon with Rails logo written next to it

Comment: @clair13 Download the image manually to your local computer (not on cloud9IDE) and save it as rails.png. Now go to your cloud9IDE workspace and don't use the 'curl' method to upload the image. Delete the current rails.png. Go to 'File' and then 'upload local file' then select the png image from your local computer and put in the correct folder in cloud9IDE.

Comment: yeah i did it with 'curl' method.But it seems there is no image on the link of the book now.so i'll download another image as you said.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm  not sure if that's correct but I believe you can do the following which makes it a bit easier to read and used to wrap blocks with an `a` tag

```
<%= link_to 'http://rubyonrails.org' do %>
  <%= image_tag ("rails.png", alt: "Rails logo") %>
<% end %>
```

The above will product an html like

```
<a href=".." >
  <img src='..' alt='..' />
</a>
```